# The date is always ignored

Tags: objective-c

I cannot understand why the date is never set in the title - it's always ignored and if I swap around the date and the title, then the title is ignored!

```
-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c title:(NSString *)t
{
 [super init];
 coordinate = c;
 NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

 [self setTitle:(@"%@%@", [today description], t)];

 //[today release];
 return self;
}
```

Comment: Why you are still using that comma expression?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
[self setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [today description], t]];
```

Your version isn't building a new string, it's just *listing* three, of which the last one is used. That's the behaviour of a bunch of expressions in brackets separated by commas like this in C.